# How can I merge two oracle database with same application running in two instances

Tags: database, oracle, merge

I have two companies using same application running in Oracle Database. Now the companies are merging and making a single company. The databases are huge with an approximate size of 10 TB.
We wanted to have the application in two databases to be merged and have a single application pointed to both the databases with minimal work.

Help is highly appreciated.

Regards
Bjm

Answer (score 0):

Using `DB Links` feature in Oracle

For more information you can use below link regarding Database Links:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm#ADMIN12083

It would enable you to build a SQL statement that references tables from the two different databases.

If you want to access the data in instance B from the instance A, you can use below query and edit the details accordingly:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK dblink_example
CONNECT TO xxusernamexx IDENTIFIED BY xxpasswordxx
USING
'(DESCRIPTION=
(ADDRESS=
(PROTOCOL=TCP)
(HOST=xxipaddrxx / xxhostxx )
(PORT=xxportxx))
(CONNECT_DATA=
(SID=xxsidxx)))';
```

Now you can execute the below query to access the table:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename@dblink_example;
```

You can perform any operation `DML, DDL, DQL` using DB Link